# Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document' jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some trouble pulling data and insert into some div. I got `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document'`. I used jquery `get` to fetch the data and loops it inside `div#contentbox`, some data are pulled but some generates failure to execute `'write' on 'Document'`. I think the document.write() fails to load after the document ready function.

Code below is the sample data to fetch using `get`:

```
<?php 
  $urlRedirect = urlencode('[VALUE_URL_REDIRECT_STACK_PAGE]&id=74');
?>
<div id="tiburon2">

<!-- START: Tiburon Inline Multi 2-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://someurl.com/generateplacementscript.aspx?placement=90989400&publisher=525182&affid=CD[VALUE_REV_TRACKER]&subid=&firstname=[VALUE_FIRST_NAME]&lastname=[VALUE_LAST_NAME]&email=[VALUE_EMAIL]&dob=[VALUE_DOBMONTH]/[VALUE_DOBDAY]/[VALUE_DOBYEAR]&zip=[VALUE_ZIP]&gender=[VALUE_GENDER_FULL]&ethnicity=&phone=[VALUE_PHONE1]-[VALUE_PHONE2]-[VALUE_PHONE3]&address=[VALUE_ADDRESS1]&redirect=<?php echo $urlRedirect ?>"></script>
<!-- END: Tiburon Inline --> 
<center><input name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="submit_button_form" type="submit" onclick="javascript: return TMG_CheckForClick();" /></center>

</div>
```

Update with the data fetch:

```js
 <?php if ($_SESSION['campaigns'] > 0) : ?>
    // get campaigns data
    var campaigns = [];
     campaigns = <?php echo json_encode($campaign_link) ?>;
    var campaignCount = campaigns.length - 1;
    var url = '<?php echo $url; ?>'
    var num = 0;
    var barcount = '<?php echo $bar ?>';
    var bar = barcount;
    var progress = '<?php echo display_progress_bar($bar, $bar_num, true); ?>';
    $('#progbar').append(progress);
    $('.button-btn-submit').append('<button id="submit_stack_button" type="button" class="submit_button_form" align="absmiddle">Submit</button>');

    var fetchCampaign = function(){
    var link = 'http://pfrprefetch.dev/dynamic_live/survey_stack_curl.php?'+ url + 'get_stack_campaign_content_php?'+ campaigns[num];
     $.get(link, function(data){
      var display = '';
      if (num  > 0) {
       var display = 'display: none;';
      }
      if (campaigns[num] == 'undefined') {
       alert('undefined campaign');
      }
      if ($('li[data-id="'+ num +'"]').text() != '{"message":"Campaign does not exists."}') {
       // console.log('num:' + num);
       $('#contentbox ul').append('<li data-id="'+ num +'" style="list-style:none;'+ display +'">' + data + '</li>');
       $('#contentbox ul').find('#submit_stack_button').remove();

       if ($('#contentbox ul li').length == 0) {
        alert('empty li');
       }
      }
      num++;
     })
     .done(function(){
      if (num <= campaignCount) {
       $('#contentbox').waitMe("hide");
       fetchCampaign();
      }
     });
    }
 
    fetchCampaign();

    var countClick = 0;
    var bar = barcount;
    // Catch submit button
  $('#submit_stack_button').on('click', function(e){
   $('li[data-id="'+ countClick +'"] form').each(function () {
         if($(this).find('.new-yesno-button input:radio:checked').first().length > 0) $(this).submit();
    });

   bar = +($('#progress_bar_current_number').text()) + 1;
   
   $("tr#progress_bar_row td:nth-child("+bar+")").toggleClass('cell_shade cell_noshade');
   $('#progress_bar_current_number').text(bar);

   $('li[data-id="'+ countClick +'"]').remove();
   countClick++;

   $('li[data-id="'+ countClick +'"]').show();
   // setTimeout(function(){
   //      if($("#contentbox ul li" ).size() == 0)
   //       window.location.href = 'http://someurl.com/no_loading/survey_stack.php?campaign='+ (countClick + 1);
   //    }, 100);
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

   <?php else: ?>
    console.log('%c Campaings not ready! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can't use `document.write` after page has loaded...it wipes out everything in the page and browsers have started preventing it also. Where is the code that does it? it's not shown here. That script url is meaningless to us. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl, Hi thanks for that. I just updated my post. Thanks

Comment: No document.write in new code either. Leaving something critical out here for us to even know what causes it. My guess is it's a third party script

Comment: @charlietfl, yeah, It's a 3rd oarty script that blocks it. We used now jquery to load all content in the background to improve website performance but I'm blocked by this thing.

Comment: Well unless you get third party to change their script not much you can do about it other than to include it on intiial page load

Comment: @charlietfl, yeah. I guess there's no other solution to this. I'll try what you said. Thanks